# Teraterm to show hex data

Tags: embedded, uart, digital-communications, rs232, protocol

I am getting UART data from micro-controller to PC. Micro-controller sends data in hex(eg.0x1B) format which can range from 0x00 to 0xFF. I want teraterm to display the received data in hex format. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Put it in debug mode or use Realterm. Voting to close as not a valid EE question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a valid EE question in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah this should probably have been posted on Super User or SO.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't possible. You need to get a different terminal software.